# @FacesConverter without converter-id and forClass

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2

What should work properly if I do not specify the converter-id and(or) forClass in determining the @FacesConverter annotation?
For example:

```
@FacesConverter
public class SplitConverter implements Converter{

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        String value) {
    //...
}
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object value) {
    //...

}
```

After registred in faces-config.xml and use that on .xhtml page:

```
<h:inputText id="badges" value="#{article.badges}" 
    required="true">
    <f:converter converterId="com.katcgr.SplitConverter" />
</h:inputText>
```

And all is work. The documentation say that

> if converter-id is the empty string, Application.addConverter(java.lang.Class,java.lang.String) is called, passing the converter-for-class as the first argument and the derived converter-class as the second argument.

But why everything works fine even if I not specified the forClass ?

Comment: *"After registred in faces-config.xml"* how exactly? You're thus basically manually registering the converter via `<converter>` entry in XML instead of relying on `@FacesConverter`? Registration in XML should be totally unnecessary in case you're using annotations.

Comment: @BalusC Yes, I have installed PrimeFaces. Also I see that converter is working without specifing `converterId ` . Just only some extensions, such as `pe:CKEditor` does not work properly.

Comment: @BalusC Thank you, I think I got the answer to my question. As I understand it, it works more or less stable, because I have PrimeFaces in project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *After registred in faces-config.xml*

Registration via `@FacesConverter` and `<converter>` in `faces-config.xml` are mutually exclusive whereby the XML registration **overrides** any annotation registration. So, when your converter is referenced via the converter ID as registered in XML, then the converter instance behaves basically exactly as if it had no annotations. If you remove the XML registration, then you should have retrieved the below exception on specified `converterId`:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: com.katcgr.SplitConverter not found.
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createConverter(ApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.createConverter(ApplicationWrapper.java:393)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ConverterTagHandlerDelegateImpl.createConverter(ConverterTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:158)
    ...
```

This would basically only work if you had a

```
@FacesConverter("com.katcgr.SplitConverter")
```

If you however remove both the XML configuration and the `<f:converter>`, then it will "work" because the `@FacesConverter` without an explicit `forClass` will be automatically invoked for every bean property which is an instance of `java.lang.Object` (basically, everything), which does not have a more specific converter already registered. In other words, your converter will behave like:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=Object.class)
```

It hopefully doesn't need an elaborate explanation that this is a terribly bad idea. It will also confuse PrimeFaces, because it will then internally initialize and use it as default converter for `String` class.